# Can't set SSP mode in Bluez through DBus

Tags: bluetooth, dbus, bluez, gdbus, ssp

I need to change the **Secure Simple Pairing mode** programmatically, but I can't figure out how to set SSP mode on or off in Bluez using a DBus command.

Using `btmgmt` utility, I just do:

```
btmgmt ssp off
btmgmt ssp on
```

Ok, but what I need is rather **DBus method calls** that I can include in my application.

But the [Bluez documentation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc) doesn't seem to mention any DBus method to change the SSP mode.

Does anyone know how to do that? (a `gdbus call` or `dbus-send` example would be just great).

Or is this just impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way you can do this using DBus. Bluez has no DBus API for this. You need to either use Bluetooth Management socket interface to toggle SSP mode or you can do this using bluez deprecated HCI interface.

To know how to use Bluetooth Management sockets see **bluez-5-X/doc/mgmt-api.txt** file in bluez-5.X source directory. Command code to toggle SSP is `0x000B`. Actually, this is how `btmgmt` tool enables/disables SSP. It uses Bluetooth Management socket. Search keyword `ssp` in **bluez-5.X/tools/btmgmt.c** and see the sample C code.

You can also do this using deprecated hci API (not recommended). See `hci_write_simple_pairing_mode` method in **bluez-5-X/lib/hci.c**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.